# For what values of $\epsilon > 0$ is it nonetheless true that...

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

The sequence $s_n = (-1)^n$ does not converge. For what values of $\epsilon > 0$ is it nonetheless true that there is an integer N so that $|s_n-1|< \epsilon $ whenever $ n \geq N$? 
For what values of $\epsilon > 0$ is it nonetheless true that there is an integer N so that $|s_n-0|< \epsilon $ whenever $ n \geq N$? (Pictures can help.)

I have so far that $\epsilon = 2$ for part one (if that is even right) but am having trouble understanding the intuition and carry over to the second part.

Comment: For the second part, you just need $|1-0| < \epsilon$ and $|-1-0| < \epsilon$. Any $\epsilon > 1$ works

Comment: Well, if $\epsilon = 5,134,389$ then $|s_n - 1| = |\pm 1 - 1| < 5,134,389$ so $\epsilon = 5,134, 389$ will do.  Can you find a value a smaller value that will work as well?

Comment: For the second part:  Hint 1:  $|s_n - 0| = |s_n|$.  Hint 2:  $s_n = \pm 1$ if $n$ is even then $s_n = 1$.  If $n$ is odd then $s_n = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $n$ is even then $s_n = 1$.  If so then $|s_n - 1| = |1 -1| = 0$.  And if $n$ is odd then $s_n = -1$.  If so then $|s_n - 1| = |-1-1|= 2$.  So $|s_n - 1| = 0$ or $2$ and $|s_n - 1| \le 2$.  So as long as $\epsilon > 2$ it will be true that $|s_n - 1| < \epsilon$.  This is true for *all* $n$ and not just "significantly large" $n$, so we don't have to worry about there being an $N$ that $n$ has to be larger than.

Now by the same reasoning, only easier, $|s_n - 0| = |s_n|$ and if $n$ is even $s_n = 1$ and if $n$ is odd $s_n = -1$.  So $|s_n -0| = |s_n| = |\pm 1| = 1\le 1$.  So for any $\epsilon > 1$ we will always have $|s_n -0| < \epsilon$.  Again this is true for *all* $n$; not just $n > N$ for some $N$.

Comment: Thank you! This really helps!